# Postman API call returns 200 but the message is 'failed'

Tags: postman

Due to system configuration issue, I had to delete the Postman and reinstall it again.

After the Postman reinstallation, I observe few api links(while other api calls are working fine) are not working.

The failed API link in the postman returns 200 but the body message as 'failed'. Although other API links works fine and receiving the message correctly.

I tried re-installing the postman but no luck. The same link was working fine before my system profile configuration issue. I understand this is something to do with my postman and system profile configuration issue but no sure what fix I apply. This API is working fine with my colleague systems.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpKaC.jpg)

Comment: thats a response from server , nothing to do with postman. check with the api developer about what does that response means

Comment: It works fine with my colleague and it returns the genuine message. only problem with my postman or system.

Comment: did you try opening that endpoint in browser ?

Comment: check your header , body etc

Comment: yes, in browser also getting the same 'Failed!' message as output. This proves something problem within my system configuration. But other APIs('Post' method html call) are working fine in both system and Postman

Comment: Talk to dev team and see what's failing